# Reciproque version of TAF

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true ?

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ a real-valued continous function on $[a,b$]. Do we have the following statement: for every $c\in ]a,b[$ there exist a derivable fucntion $\varphi$ on $]a,b[$  such that
$$ \varphi(a) - \varphi(b) = f(c)(a-b). $$

If yes, how can we get it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Let $\phi(x) = f(c) x$.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer:)